# Passing XML date in table layout using AJAX and javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, xml-parsing

I'm able to successfully pass the XML date on my page after button click but struggling on one condition which is what if some entries are null inside the XML file how to handle that situation. Also, how do we achieve the same table layout and null condition using JSON

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
th{
   background-color:#BBB;
}
</style>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      myFunction(xhttp);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th><th>Country</th><th>Price</th><th>CompaYearny</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>"+

    x[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "&nbsp;"+

    x[i].getElementsByTagName("COMPANY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td> "+

    x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<CATALOG>
<CD>
<TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1982</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
<YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Eros</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1997</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>One night only</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1998</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.10</PRICE>
<YEAR>1973</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.50</PRICE>
<YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Romanza</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.80</PRICE>
<YEAR>1996</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
<YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Black angel</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1995</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Many</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
<YEAR>1999</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>For the good times</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
<YEAR>1995</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1997</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE>
<ARTIST></ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY></COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
<YEAR>1971</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY>
<PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1996</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>The very best of</TITLE>
<ARTIST></ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>K</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Island</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Stop</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE>
<ARTIST>T'Pau</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY></COMPANY>
<PRICE></PRICE>
<YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1983</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY>
<PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
<YEAR>1983</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY></COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1991</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
<PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Picture book</TITLE>
<ARTIST></ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY></COMPANY>
<PRICE>7.20</PRICE>
<YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Red</TITLE>
<ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>London</COMPANY>
<PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
<YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
<YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: `what if some entries are null inside the XML file` - there's no null in your example XML file - so ... probably don't have to worry about it - or change null to empty string

Comment: I want to create a condition where even null entries are also accepted anyway to do that

Comment: define a  null entry. You mean empty, or non-existent?

Comment: have you thought of using xslt?

Comment: I've made some amends in the XML file. please have a  look now. I meant what if some entries does not exist, how do we tackle that situation.

Comment: What am I looking for, champ

Comment: Also, if you have a solution in mind for XML case can we apply the same to JSON as well.  Thanks

Comment: I don't see a problem with `passing Date` - as you have no Date object to deal with

Comment: Here is the error I was getting: "index.html:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined"  if either one of the fields gets missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function:

```
function smartValue(root, tag) {
    return (root.getElementsByTagName(tag).length &&
            root.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0].childNodes.length &&
            root.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
           ) || '';
}
```

then, instead of

```
x[i].getElementsByTagName("whatever")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

do

```
smartValue(x[i], "whatever")
```

Comment: Thanks, Jaromanda X, but not working at my end. Do you have any fiddle or jsbin link available where you might have tested this.

Comment: Awesome, this code works. Just one more how will we test the same condition on JSON file? Thanks

Comment: I would do it similarly - depending on your JSON